# Django Queryset : Remove 'u' to compare between unicode and string

Tags: django

How to remove 'u' from Django Queryset.

Let say I have result from my QuerySet `<QuerySet [u'MANAGER']>`

How to remove the <`QuerySet [u' ']>` so that I get the result as `MANAGER` only.

Because i want to compare the result with another string from API object.

This my code

```
role = Notifications.objects.all().values_list('role', flat=True)
    rname=str(role)
    lists = services.get_user('name', 'first_name')
    for o in lists:
        email = o["email"]
        group = o["groups"]
        # print group

        for obj in group:
            group_name = obj["name"]

        if group_name == rname:
            print "YES"
        else:
            print "NO"
```

The result that i got is `NO`. I want to get the result as `YES`

Comment: You do not need remove it, that means unicode.

Comment: Just access the result directly, you will get `MANAGER`.

Comment: What do you mean by access the result directly? @aquaman

Comment: @MunirohMansoor I mean something similar to what @aircraft is trying to say. You do not need to remove it. BTW what is the problem with `u''` anyways?

Comment: @aquaman sorry. i didn't elaborate more on my question.. It is because i want to compare the queryset result with another string from API object.

Comment: @MunirohMansoor Well in that case please edit your question so that things can be more clear to people. And please post some code too that you have tried.

Comment: @aquaman question edited

Comment: Please share some of your code. Like what is your model, your API object, how are you comparing till now and what is the problem with what are you trying. We cannot suggest any answer to you without some information.

Comment: since 'role' is an array of roles .. if you want to compare group_name matches one of the role then use => if group_name in role:  print "YES"

Comment: @SajiXavier wow.. it works.. thank you so much...

Comment: good .. added it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `values_list` returns an array of roles. if you want to check whether `group_name` is present in the roles, then you should use ...

```
    if group_name in role:
        print "YES"
    else:
        print "NO"
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about the part `lists = services.get_user('name', 'first_name')` but I see some mistakes over here -

```
role = Notifications.objects.all().values_list('role', flat=True)
    rname=str(role)
```

your *role* variable is not any value that you can convert into string. *role* is an **array** here. So you better do something like -

```
role = Notifications.objects.all().values_list('role', flat=True)
        rname=str(role[0])
```